# Get a breakdown of DOT for an account

Tags: data-analytics, accountdata

For any given account can I get a breakdown of DOT that is bonded, vested, locked, transferable, locked for democracy etc.

Ideally looking for way to do it through py-substrate-interface or PolkadotJs api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using PolkadotJS, this is the code to get the breakdown of a DOT for an account in the current block (change the block hash if you want to query it in an specific block).

```js
    const ADDR = 'your-address-here';
    const currentBlock = await api.rpc.chain.getBlock();
    const apiAt = await api.at(currentBlock.block.header.hash);
    const accountInfo = await apiAt.query.system.account(ADDR);
    const locks = await apiAt.query.balances.locks(ADDR)
    console.log(`Balance of the account ${ADDR} is: `);
    console.log(accountInfo.toHuman());
    console.log(locks.toHuman());
```

The account info will return the basic information of your balance account (free balance, reserved, miscFrozen and feeFrozen. Example:

```json
    {
     nonce: '4',
     consumers: '1',
     providers: '1',
     sufficients: '0',
     data: {
       free: 'xx',
       reserved: 'xx',
       miscFrozen: 'xx',
       feeFrozen: 'xx'
     }
   }
```

The locks constant will show you the bonded, vested, locked...
Example( with vested tokens):

```json
    [ { id: 'vesting ', amount: 'xx', reasons: 'Misc' } ]
```